# Can't render a partial from the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a kind of blog and would like the render a partial from my controller if a condition is true.

This is my controller method:

```
    def comments_session
        render partial: 'comments/form' if signed_in?
        render partial: 'comments/show'
    end
```

And this is my view:

```
<%= comments_session %>
```

These are my partials:

_show.html.erb

```
<% @post.comments.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse.each do |comment| %>
<div class="col-lg-12 mt-3 pt-3 border-top">
  <% if signed_in? %>
    <% if current_user.username == comment.user.username %>
      <%= link_to 'Excluir', post_comment_path(@post, comment), :class =>"btn btn-sm btn-danger btn_round float-right border-dark", 
      method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Deseja realmente excluir esse comentário?"} %>
    <% else %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
  <% end %>
  <h6><strong>~ <%= comment.user.username %></strong></h6>
  <p class="comment"><%= comment.body %></p>
  <p class="lead distance_of_time"><small>
    <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %>
  </small></p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: @comment, url: [@post, @comment], local: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 form-group">
      <%= f.text_area :body, :class =>"form-control", :placeholder =>"Escreva o Que Quiser!" %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1 form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Comentar", :class =>"btn btn-lg btn-primary border-dark text-light" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The method renders "_show.html.erb" perfectly, but doesn't do the same with the other...
I tried to change and remove the condition, but it didn't work :/

Please, I'd like to know why I can't render it
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this way?

```
def comments_session
  return render partial: 'comments/form' if signed_in?
  render partial: 'comments/show'
end
```

I think you're getting a `DoubleRenderError` or something like that

Comment: It happens because if you don't return, it finds two renders and that's a problem (it's ambiguous at least)

Answer (score 1):

Rails is not allowed to render more than one partial in controller.

```
def comments_session
  if signed_in?
    render partial: 'comments/form'
  else
    render partial: 'comments/show'
  end
end
```